# How we can add our app accessible from other apps, like gif in whatsapp and linkedin? Is there any good tutorial to follow?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, gif, whatsapp

I want to create my app sdk same like gif in whatsapp, we can share gif when gallery is opened from whatsapp similarly i want to add my app which could be accessible from other apps. Any idea how can i work on this?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is `App Extensions`.

You can find Apple's documentation on the same here- [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)

Here are some other good tutorials:

1. https://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-8-app-extensions
2. https://www.yudiz.com/share-extention-in-ios-app/
3. https://www.9spl.com/blog/build-share-extension-ios-using-swift/